# problem with bulk data update in sql

Tags: sql

i have this values in a coulmn say accountno in table record:

```
1,002
1,044
1,086
1,108
1,126
1,190
1,226
1,258
1,260
```

now i want to update them as

```
1002
1044
1086
1108
1126
1190
1226
1258
1260
```

the column is of type string. how can i do it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming you are using SQL server -

```
update table 
set accountno = REPLACE(accountno,',', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE record
SET accountno = replace(accountno,',','')
```